# Code Igniter Session: Unable to store value to session from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When I try to insert some value into session from a controller function, it doesn't store the value.

I don't have the problem in storing session when checking login. But in another controller (I try to save into session to enable searching) and try printing the value in another controller, the ones that are recently inserted goes blank.

Its weird because I have followed all the rules of assigning values to session in Code Igniter.

The controller code is

```
$this->session->set_userdata("langId",$lang[0]->languageId);   
$this->session->set_userdata("direction",$lang[0]->direction);
```

Comment: Please share your controller code.

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata("langId",$lang[0]->languageId);   
                $this->session->set_userdata("direction",$lang[0]->direction);

Comment: did you echo `$lang[0]->languageId` does it print a value.? and also print `$lang[0]->direction`

Comment: yes Sir, I did echo them...and that's how I came to know they are blank.

Comment: Are you saying that both $lang[0]->languageID and $lang[0]->direction are blanck? OR just $this->session->userdata("langID") is blank?

Comment: So your language values are blank,right?

Comment: lets see the `$lang` array

Comment: I am asking you to echo the variable value you are setting to the session i suspect they are blank,hence the session value is blank.

Comment: @damien only the ones I inserted then like search variable are blank. However, the ones that are inserted prior like username, email id stays(they don't go blank)

Comment: @RPM here is the $lang thing.. $lang=$this->language_model->getLanguageCode($pageRq['lang']);

Comment: @ganeshrj I have double checked it before and after entering the value, they are all intact and ok. Just I don't understand why doesn't it gets stored in the sessison.

Comment: are you sure? print_r($lang) gives you what please share that info here

Comment: @ganeshrj this is the result.. Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [languageId] => 2
           [name] => Japanese
           [code] => jp
           [direction] => 0
           [isEnabled] => 1
           [modifiedBy] => 
           [dateModified] => 2012-12-22 05:39:54
           [status] => 1
       )

)

Comment: and am sorry about the delays in replying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this should work

`$this->session->set_userdata("langId",$lang->languageId);

$this->session->set_userdata("direction",$lang->direction);`